# Django : transform a function download view into a class view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-file-upload

I am trying to rewrite a function view that download files into a classview.
However I don't see how to do it properly with the right methods, since I have an argument from the url. Then I do not which on of the class view I should be using.

I did an attemps that is worrking, but I do not see why it works with a get method. Anyone can explain me ?

Here is my function view that is working:

##### Function views.py:

```
def download(request, fileUUID):
    file = Documents.objects.get(Uuid=fileUUID)
    filename = file.Filename
    
    file_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
    url = file.Url
    blob_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    blob_content = AzureBlob().download_from_blob(blob_name=blob_name)

    if blob_content:
        response = HttpResponse(blob_content.readall(), content_type=file_type)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'
        messages.success(request, f"{filename} was successfully downloaded")
        return response

    return Http404
```

##### urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from upload.views import *


urlpatterns = [ 
    path('upload/', DocumentUpload.as_view(), name="upload"),
    path('download/<str:fileUUID>/', DocumentDownload.as_view(), name="download"),
   ]
```

##### template file or html:

```
<a href="{% url 'download' file.Uuid %}">
       <i class='bx bxs-download'></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path for `download` class based view:

```py
 path('download/<str:fileUUID>/',views.DownloadView.as_view())
```

The view from the [`View`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#view):

```py
class DownloadView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file = UploadFilesBlobStorage.objects.get(Uuid=self.kwargs['fileUUID'])
        filename = file.Filename
        file_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
        url = file.Url
        blob_name = url.split("/")[-1]
        blob_content = download_from_blob(blob_name)

        if blob_content:
            response = HttpResponse(blob_content.readall(), content_type=file_type)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'
            messages.success(request, f"{filename} was successfully downloaded")
            return response

        return Http404
```

Comment: @sunderam_dubey why not the Detail view?

Comment: @MaximDanilov Op doesn't clarified the view to be used?

Comment: in django exists many class views, one of them - DetailView. Detail view get  UploadFilesBlobStorage object in box. Class View - not. If you help change function to View, try to choose correct view for task.

Comment: @MaximDanilov Oo don't know about that, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @SunderamDubey thank you for your answer. I did like you and it works. However, I do not understand the role of the get method. Is is not possible to use an get_context_data. I try to understand

Comment: @Goncalves Yes, that's too possible, but get() method is straight forward for get requests.